# Adding picture after a link. Link opens in parent window, while picture opens in new window

Tags: html, css

I want to add an image (an icon) after every link with a certain class.

The link itself should open in the parent window, while the image/icon should also be the same link, but it will open in a new window when clicked.

For example:

HTML (opens in parent window):

```
<a href="link.com" class="icon">Link</a>
```

CSS (add image with same link, but opens in new window):

```
.icon a:after {
  content: url(/img/icons/external_link.png);
}
```

Also link same as `href` with window `_blank`

Is that possible?

Comment: This can't be achieved using CSS and HTML alone, you would either need separate <a> tags for the text and image, or a little bit of JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: I thought so... Basically, then, I would need to add make a script that adds an icon after every offsite link

Comment: Yeah, that's what you'll need. If jQuery is an option for you, the .each() function would be a good place to start: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1):

Well as said, not possible with CSS only. However you can achieve this by using some **jQuery**

```js
$(".icon").each(function() {
  $("<a href=" + $(this).attr("href") + " target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-external-link-square'></i></a>").insertAfter($(this));
})
```

```css
.icon+a {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<label><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="icon">StackOverflow</a></label><br>
<label><a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/" class="icon">StackOverflow Meta</a></label>
```

[**Fiddle Link**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/sLmxkcw0/)

Answer (score 0):

This can't be achieved using CSS and HTML alone, you would either need separate  tags for the text and image, or a little bit of JavaScript/jQuery.

If you are able to utilise jQuery, I recommend utilising the .each() function. Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each